# Question on appropriate solution to issue with IV in data (is the test still suitable?)

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I have some pre-existing data, which was collected by my predecessors. For the data I typically would conduct a Multivariate General Linear Model. In this data I am collecting information about patients (city, diagnoses), and I want to see if these two factors interact with dependant variables (recovery time, mortality).

My processors stored the recovery time on a different spreadsheet to mortality. I thought this was fine initially, as they had ID for each person so that they could be easily combined to do the analysis.

Then I realised my problem. The Independent factor/variable is different for each persons ID (person 1 has a IV of California, schizophrenia on one spreadsheet, but on the other spreadsheet they have an IV of California, Bipolar). So it looks like data relates to different people.

I am going to take the bet that I must now do separate analysis for each spreadsheet, but I wanted to check if anyone had any recommendations? As I don't want to keep doing many separate tests and get P value >0.5 by chance.

***note this is fake variables. but its to give you a sense of what the issue is.
Edit: Amended the variables as one of the IV's were the same, the second wasn't.